# Meaning of a bit of perl's Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm translating code from perl and I've come accross the following line

```
$text =~ s/([?!\.][\ ]*[\'\"\)\]\p{IsPf}]+) +([\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]*[\ ]*[\p{IsUpper}])/$1\n$2/g;
```

My question is, what does \p{IsPf} and \p{IsPi} match to? I've tried searching online for it but haven't found anything...

Comment: As an aside: There are lots of unneccessary backslashes in that regex, and two unneccessary captures. `s/[?!.][ ]*['")\]\p{IsPf}]+\K +(?=['"([¿¡\p{IsPi}]*[ ]*[\p{IsUpper}])/\n/g` should be equivalent for practical purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's ask [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com): It's a Unicode character property.

[image: RegexBuddy Screenshot]

You can find more [documentation on Unicode character properties and Unicode scripts here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 12):

`\p{..}` matches characters by their unicode character properties: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties

In particular, `\p{IsPf}` matches characters with the "[final punctuation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pf/list.htm)" property, and `\p{IsPi}` matches charactes with the "[initial punctuation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pi/list.htm)" property. These seem to be mostly closing and opening quotes.

The point of the substitution seems to be breaking sentences into separate lines by matching the end and beginning of a sentence, taking into account that a sentence may start and end with various types of punctuation.

Comment: Many thanks. Both yours and Tim's answers would have been perfect... unfortunately I have to pick one and not both..

Answer (score 3):

As a bit of extra information, `unichars` from [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle) can be used to list the matching characters.

```
$ unichars -au '\p{IsPi}' | cat
 «  U+000AB LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ‘  U+02018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ‛  U+0201B SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
 “  U+0201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
 ‟  U+0201F DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
 ‹  U+02039 SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ⸂  U+02E02 LEFT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
 ⸄  U+02E04 LEFT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
 ⸉  U+02E09 LEFT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET
 ⸌  U+02E0C LEFT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET
 ⸜  U+02E1C LEFT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET
 ⸠  U+02E20 LEFT VERTICAL BAR WITH QUILL

$ unichars -au '\p{IsPf}' | cat
 »  U+000BB RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ’  U+02019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ”  U+0201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
 ›  U+0203A SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ⸃  U+02E03 RIGHT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
 ⸅  U+02E05 RIGHT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
 ⸊  U+02E0A RIGHT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET
 ⸍  U+02E0D RIGHT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET
 ⸝  U+02E1D RIGHT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET
 ⸡  U+02E21 RIGHT VERTICAL BAR WITH QUILL
```